# PrimeNg Dropdown get ng-dirty class when its options update from API on page load

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

1. Firstly I create from with initial values.
2. Then call API to fill the dropdown options.
3. When page loaded I notice
   that all dropdown have red border and have ng-dirty class before any
   edit from UI.

***Note**: I tried to make form pristine using: ***makeAsPristine()*** but
nothing change.*

```
<p-dropdown _ngcontent-fxt-c428="" formcontrolname="costCenterId" optionvalue="id" class="p-element p-inputwrapper ng-tns-c200-4 ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-star-inserted ng-dirty">
```

creation form:
[image]

Dropdown:
[image]

call API to fill projectpaymentMethods list:
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you present a little more code of your component and template ?

Comment: I have edited the question, check it now. @AlainBoudard

Comment: I can't reproduce :( ... don't you have some `patchValue()` or `setValue()` call on your FormGroup ?

Comment: you mean to call `setValue()` instead of create form in this way ? @AlainBoudard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue today and I could only solve it with css magic:

```
::ng-deep p-dropdown.ng-untouched.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  .p-dropdown {
    border-color: #ced4da;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have this issue too, but this is not the way it should be solved. Because it affects on validation and in some cases which it must be red, it is not red because of setting this style.